# Beamer+pgfpages = "pdfTeX warning (dest): Page 31 has been referenced but does not exist!"

Tags: beamer, pgfpages

I am using

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]
```

and get a string of errors of the form

pdfTeX warning (dest): Page X has been referenced but does not exist!

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
  pdfstartview=FitH,
  bookmarksopen=true}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{bookmark}

\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\beamer@@frametitle}{\only<1>{\bookmark[page=\the\c@page,level=3]    {#1}}}%
{\message{** patching of \string\beamer@@frametitle succeeded **}}%
{\errmessage{** patching of \string\beamer@@frametitle failed **}}%
\makeatother

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]

\title{Test}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add a small complete (=compilable) document that shows the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the framtitle patch might not be necessary in `handout` mode:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
 pdfstartview=FitH,
 bookmarksopen=true}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{bookmark}


\makeatletter
\apptocmd{\beamer@@frametitle}{\only<1|handout:0>{\bookmark[page=\the\c@page,level=3]{#1}}}%
{\message{** patching of \string\beamer@@frametitle succeeded **}}%
{\errmessage{** patching of \string\beamer@@frametitle failed **}}%
\makeatother


\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]


\title{Test}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{itemize}
\item Test
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Well, I actually use bookmarks in handout mode. I find that TeX runs faster in handout mode, and that it is easier to edit in handout mode. Then I turn off handout mode when I'm ready to present. However, I don't need bookmarks when I use pgfpages. So I think I can use your idea to get what I want. Thanks!